# Range of a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that T is a linear operator from V to V, is the range(T) a subspace of V?

If range(T)=V, then it is clear that range(T) is a subspace of V since V itself is a vector space. However, what if range(T) does not equal V? How can I show that it will still be a subspace or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this; if I'm corrected so be it.

I'll call `range(T) = W`

Since we're told that T maps to V, it's clear that W is a subset of V. So we just have to prove that W is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

For any w1, w2 elements of W, there exists v1, v2 elements of V such that

`T(v1) = w1` and `T(v2) = w2`

Also, since T is a linear oeprator,

`T(v1) + T(v2) = T(v1 + v2)`

and since T(v1 + v2) is an element of W, w1 + w2 is an element of W.

Thus I believe I just proved W to be closed under addition.

A similar tact can be taken to prove scalar multiplication.

Comment: @ Steve Hastings:  other that tacitly referring to tact as a *tactic*, your answer stabs through to the heart of the matter! +1!